# Output text between integers in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a string of text that I would like to break up into multiple strings between integers.

```
$string = "1 This is the first sentence. 2 This is the second sentence, 3 hello world!";
```

I want to output it to:

```
$string1 = "1 This is the first sentence.";
$string2 = "2 This is the second sentence,";
$stirng3 = "3 hello world!";
```

Or an array is fine too

Comment: What happens when the string contains a number? `1 This is 1st sentence.` What have you tried?

Comment: You're also losing the space between the end of one sentance and the number at the start of the next. Is that deliberate?

Comment: @tom looking at all my data I don't have an integer within the sentence I'm string to extract

Comment: @ChadPriddle If you can ensure that you will never have a number in a sentence, then great. But it is quite common to have numbers in sentences. For example: `In 1990 I was only three years old.`, `There are 900 products in our store.`

Comment: @tom Excellent that worked! but what if the array goes past 9 strings? It removes one of the integers: 1 sentence... 2 sentence... - 9 sentence... 0 sentence... 1 sentence... etc.

Comment: @ChadPriddle: What are you talking about? I'm confused.

Comment: @tom with the answer below, after it loops through more than 9 on the array it is removing a digit. To make it more clear each sentence is a verse in a poem and I want each sentence to start with the number but after it does the array it goes 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,etc instead of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,etc.

Comment: @ChadPriddle Add a +: `[0-9]+ [^0-9]+`

Answer (score 6):

This will work for your use case, but might break otherwise.

```
preg_match_all("/[0-9]+ [^0-9]+/", $string, $matches);
```

Will give you in `$matches`

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(30) "1 This is the first sentence. "
    [1]=>
    string(31) "2 This is the second sentence, "
    [2]=>
    string(14) "3 hello world!"
  }
}
```

You could use a `trim()` to get rid of the extra spaces.

---

You may also be interested in [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) if you don't need the integers

```
preg_split("/[0-9]+/", $strings);
```

Which returns

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
  [1]=>
  string(29) " This is the first sentence. "
  [2]=>
  string(30) " This is the second sentence, "
  [3]=>
  string(13) " hello world!"
}
```

Comment: It works great but after it loops through more than 9 on the array it is removing a digit. To make it more clear each sentence is a verse in a poem and I want each sentence to start with the number but after it does the array it goes 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,etc instead of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,etc.

Comment: See the updated answer `/[0-9]+ [^0-9]+/`